# AutoIt. string search and replace

Tags: string, autoit

I have multiple files in one folder(ini files). in each file, between the lines i have some lines that look like this

```
[12.3] ; here are some random numbers 

task = task0013

... some more lines

[74.1]

task = task6435

... and so on and so forth
```

The numbers after "task" are not in any particular order, ie either ascending or descending.

Now in another ini file (A) all the Values from all the files are stored as [SectionName]:

```
[task0013]

name=whatever

[task6452]

name=bla bla bla

... etc
```

What I want to do is to add the Value from the ini file (A) as a new line to the corresponding [SectionName] in all of those ini files at the begining, so it will look like this:

```
[12.3] ; here are some random numbers 

task = task0013

whatever

some other lines 

[74.1]

task = task6435

...
```

Comment: Is adding the task name only as a value (without the corresponding key) a strict requirement? AFAIK, Autoit's ini manipulation functions don't support this. However, if 'name = whatever' is allowed instead of just 'whatever', this is trivial to do.

Comment: Could you please provide 3 samples. File A File B and the result File C. So that I can read those files and test ist on my own. Reading whatever (everything after name= in any section) should not be a problem. Finding the keyword "task0013 and then add a new line should be easy too.

Comment: @d0c adding the task name only as a value is not strict requirement

Comment: @Xenobiologist File B is big and it has all the values for all the files type A and also for some other type of file that i dont need  Files type A can have just one name in in or more. I want to mention that in file B there are sone section names that doesnt have the string 'task' in in at all

Answer (score 0):

Give this here a try. It will modify existing name entries to match the ones in A.ini and add new ones if they don't exist. You'll have to copy the script file inside the folder containing all the ini files (A.ini or whatever you call it should also be in there). Make sure to backup your files first, as this script will modify existing files, not create new ones.

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <File.au3>

Local $filenames = _FileListToArray(@ScriptDir)
Local $filenameA = "A.ini"

For $i = 1 To $filenames[0]
   ;ConsoleWrite($filenames[$i] & @CRLF)

   If StringRegExp($filenames[$i], "\.ini$") == 0 Or $filenames[$i] == $filenameA Then
      ContinueLoop
   EndIf

   Local $sectionNames = IniReadSectionNames($filenames[$i])

   For $j = 1 To $sectionNames[0]
      ;ConsoleWrite("adding data to section " & $sectionNames[$j] & " ..." & @CRLF)

      Local $curSection = IniReadSection($filenames[$i], $sectionNames[$j])

      For $k = 1 To $curSection[0][0]
         ;ConsoleWrite($curSection[$k][0] & " -> " & $curSection[$k][1] & @CRLF)

         If $curSection[$k][0] == "task" Then

            Local $newTaskName = IniRead($filenameA, $curSection[$k][1], "name", "")
            ;ConsoleWrite("name -> " & $taskName & @CRLF)
            Local $curTaskName = IniRead($filenames[$i], $sectionNames[$j], "name", "")

            If $curTaskName == "" Then
               _ArrayInsert($curSection, $k + 1, "name|" & $newTaskName, 0)
               ;_ArrayDisplay($curSection, "")
               IniWriteSection($filenames[$i], $sectionNames[$j], $curSection)
            Else
               IniWrite($filenames[$i], $sectionNames[$j], "name", $newTaskName)
            EndIf

            ExitLoop

         EndIf

      Next
   Next
Next
```